# Javascript: Running a while loop with an if statement to randomly generate things with a clause

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random, do-while, phaser-framework

Ok, so my question is very specific. I'm attempting to randomly generate a game stage for a 2D platformer I'm making. I want the platforms to be a set distance apart and I want the number of platforms created to be configureable. I believe the best way to do this is with a while loop that has an if statement nested in it, I've attempted it but can't get it working. Here's what I've tried.

```
var numLedges = 10;
var lastLedge;
var xSpace = randomIntFromInterval(0, 600);
var ySpace = randomIntFromInterval(0, 400);
var currentLedgeX = xSpace;
var currentLedgeY = ySpace;
var lastLedgeX = -1000;
var lastLedgeY = -1000;
var i = 0;
var loopCount = 0;
var maxLoops = 100;

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function createLedges() {
        do {   // This is supposed to make sure the platforms are being created 100px away in any direction
                if (currentLedgeX > lastLedgeX + 100 || currentLedgeX <     lastLedgeX - 100 && currentLedgeY > lastLedgeY + 100 || currentLedgeY <     lastLedgeY - 100) {
// Creates a ledge using phaser that is roughly 40 x 40px
                    var currentLedge = stillLedge.create(currentLedgeX,     currentLedgeY, 'platform');
                    currentLedge.body.immovable = true;
                    lastLedgeX = currentLedgeX;
                    lastLedgeY = currentLedgeY;
                    i++;
                }
            loopCount++;
        } while (i != numLedges || loopCount < maxLoops)
}
```

This doesn't appear to loop or it turns into an infinite loop somewhat randomly. If someone can think of a better way of doing this or a way to make this work I'd appreciate it. I'm out of ideas and haven't been able to find anything useful on the subject.

Here's a quick example of what's happening using an old tutorial's game. [CLICK](http://preview.c9.io/nightstick24/phaser_game-testing/testingThings.html?_c9_id=livepreview6&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io)

Comment: I think the problem is `i != numLedges`. The case where `i == numLedges` could be the turning point where `loopCount < maxLoops` stops being true. Then, the next iteration puts `i != numLedges` and then the loop clause is irrelevant for the rest of execution, since `i` will never get back to `numLedges`. Does that make sense? Try printing out your loop condition variables and see what's happening.

Comment: Also, it might make more sense to do `while (i != numLedges && i < maxLoops)`. `maxLoops` seems a lot like `maxLedges`.

Comment: `Ok, so my question is very specific.` terrific.

Comment: Maybe i'm reading it wrong, but after you create a ledge and set lastLedgeX equal to currentLedgeX (and Y), currentLedgeX (and Y) never changes after that, i dont think. So, for instance, if currentLedgeX starts at 600, it will trigger the if statement, and lastLedgeX will become 600. Then it will check again, but currentLedgeX will be 600 and lastLedgeX will also be 600, and they'll never change

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I see what you're saying Tony, not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that.

I'll try that and get back to you PremierBromanov, I was just thinking that might be the problem as I was able to only get it to spawn what appeared to be one platform once. It was probably all of them stacked on top of each other, good observation!

vol7ron, I was tired when I wrote this, cut me some slack!

Comment: @Nightstick24 welcome to SO.  That was not sarcastic; it's good to be specific and not general — questions that are *general* in nature are often closed and downvoted.  Don't forget to upvote the answers that helped you and select an answer that solved your question (you get points for doing that).  Points open up different features of the site, depending on how involved you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your loop condition `while (i != numLedges || loopCount < maxLoops)`. It's creating a weird behavior because you can't tell before the program is run when both of the conditions on either side of the `||` will evaluate to true at the same time (if ever in the case of an infinite loop). Basically you've created a race condition, if `i` becomes greater than 10 (`numLedges`) before `loopCount` has reached 100 then you're stuck in an infinite loop.

> You probably wanted an AND condition `&&` like @Tony suggested above in a comment:

`while (i != numLedges || loopCount < maxLoops)`

#### I've offered an explanation below:

Look at it with the constant variables replaced with their numeric values:

`while (i != 10 || loopCount < 100)`

And consider this very literal example of what you're telling the program to do:

```
(i != 10) // will always be true except for when i is 10
```

**OR**

```
(loopCount < 100) // will be true until loopcount reaches 100
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out clearly in an answer, I realize now my mistake with that. That solves the infinite looping and constant crashing upon running the loop!

Comment: This runs the loop perfectly, though it will only execute once then it exits the loop. Any ideas on why it won't loop through properly?

Comment: Right now with the updated condition your loop should be running a **minimum** of 10 times and a maximum of 100. I'd suggest going through your loop with a debugger to find out exactly where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `while (i < numLedges && loopCount < maxLoops)`

Comment: Note: I gave this a quick read-through, without trying to fully comprehend what your logic was doing.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the infinite loop crashing perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This may be simpler. Forgive my syntax, I'm in AS3 mode at the moment, so I'll do my best to make it JS. I wrote this assuming you are creating left to right, top to bottom (top left origin point), but it should work in any case.

```
function getRandomBoolean() 
{
       return Math.random() < 0.5;
}
function createLedges() {
    for (i = 0; i < numLedges; i++)
    {


        lastLedgeX = currentLedgeX;
        lastLedgeY = currentLedgeY;
        var randomX = randomIntFromInterval(currentLedgeX + 100, currentLedgeX + 500);
        var randomY = randomIntFromInterval(currentLedgeY + 100, currentLedgeY + 500);
        if (getRandomBoolean()) randomX *= -1
        if (getRandomBoolean()) randomY *= -1

        currentLedgeX += randomX;
        currentLedgeY += randomY;

       var currentLedge = stillLedge.create(lastLedgeX,     lastLedgeY, 'platform');
        currentLedge.body.immovable = true;

    }
}
```

This will create exactly as many ledges as you specify and they will always be at least 100 units apart in the X and Y direction. you can change the max to whatever you'd like. Ideally, you would create those as variables, but I hard-coded it for easy reading

Comment: I'll try this ASAP and get back to you, it seems simpler and I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This is looping through properly, though it appears to only be making two different platforms, when it should be making 10.

Comment: @Nightstick24 It's probably making 10 in two different places. Check that randomX and randomY are different every time